# How can we list all the branches in a repo using github graphQL api?

Tags: github-api, github-graphql

I am trying to check if a branch already exists in repo for that first I need to get all the open branches present.

```
query searhbranches { 

   repositoryOwner(login: "username"){ 

      repository(name: "config-replica"){

      name 

      [branches] // something like this but its not available 

    } 

  } 

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to look at the `refs` node inside `repository`. Here's an example query that works for me:

```
{
  repository(owner: "desktop", name: "desktop") {
    refs(first: 50, refPrefix:"refs/heads/") {
      nodes {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is what it returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "refs": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "name": "add-lfs-path-lookup"
          },
          {
            "name": "add-notes-lookup-to-parser"
          },
          {
            "name": "ahead-behind-toggle-spike"
          },
          {
            "name": "all-stash-functions"
          },
          ...
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
...
```

Comment: It works, I am able to get the branches' name as well. Hopefully I will be able to mutate it as well. Thanks @Brendon.

Comment: If you're satisfied with the solution, don't forget to mark it as answered!