# Github graphQL API get branches of a repository sorted by pushDate

Tags: graphql, github-api

We can get all branches of a particular repository with the query mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55487432/how-can-we-list-all-the-branches-in-a-repo-using-github-graphql-api).

```graphql
query { 
    repository(owner: "<userName>", name: "<repoName>") {
    refs(first: 10, refPrefix: "refs/heads/",after:"<cursor>") {
      edges {
        node {
          name
            target {
              ... on Commit {
                author {
                  name
                  email
                  user {
                    login
                  }
                }
                pushedDate
                oid
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But would it be possible for the names to be returned in a sorted order by `pushedDate` ( or any relevant dates ) . for eg if my repository has 2 branches ( `branch 1` with pushdate as `March 1` and `branch 2` with pushDate as `March 10` I want `branch2` to be  returned before `branch 1`).

We can do that sorting manually but the issue is that my query is paginated , so this sort would just order only those branches in the current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not think this is possible. The only way you can order the branches is by `ALPHABETICAL`

e.g. `refs(first: 10, refPrefix: "refs/heads/", orderBy: {field: ALPHABETICAL, direction: DESC}`

However, assuming you do not have 1000s of branches perhaps you could, as you suggest, make all the paginated queries then order by `pushedDate`. You can get 100 nodes at a time with pagination (`first: 100`) so likely only a few queries to get all branches.